# Keep input in text field when jumping to other links

Tags: javascript, html

To explain what I mean:

1. Go to https://github.com/torvalds/linux
2. Type something in the search box at the top
3. Click on another tab (e.g., "Pull requests")
4. The URL in the address bar changes, but the text in the search box remains unchanged

However, if I manually enter the address in 4 in the browser address bar, the text will be cleared. How is the first behavior implemented?

Comment: Those who downvoted without explaining what I'm doing wrong, you are not helping the community at all. I'm new to web development and I don't see how what you are doing does any good except for raising the barrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search bar is contained in a header which is common across all the pages of the application.

Thus, when you switch the tab only the content beneath the header changes. This is the way most single page application works. So, the text in the search bar is retained.

When you manually change the address in the address bar, you are forcing the page to load again. Thus, the header is also rendered again and the text is changed.

In order to achieve this, you need to make your header same for all the pages by using templates.

Comment: But when I click on a tab, doesn't it also go to a new page at a different URL? Isn't the header also a new header (of the new page)?

Comment: Nope. It looks like a new page and new URL but it is called a new **route** in the terminology of single page apps.

Please search the web to find out more about the architecture and working of single page apps and you will get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this could be saving the text input to localStorage.

In a Single Page Application Framework like Angular you could use a service to store the value across the application. But in this case the value is also gone after a hard browser reload.